# How can I decrease ADF Mobile Android Application size

Tags: java, android, mobile, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I just develop an ADF Mobile Android App and I remark that the app size is too big according to the pages that I have inside it. I just have two pages one with outputtext and the other with list.

Can some tells me why my app is over 60 MB?
Is there a way to overcome some useless data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to package the application in Release mode - this will cut it down to about 10MB (which include the JVM).
See instructions here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/speed_up_adf_mobile_deployment